# Encapsulate sibling elements [two at a time] which share same class with a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have ten sibling elements that have class `.post`,
markup is something like:

```
<div class='book'>
    <div class='post text'>one</div>
    <div class='post photo'>two</div>
    <div class='post quote'>three</div>
    <div class='post video'>four</div>
    <div class='post audio'>five</div>
    <div class='post link'>six</div>
    <div class='post text'>seven</div>
    <div class='post video'>eight</div>
    <div class='post quote'>nine</div>
    <div class='post link'>ten</div>
</div>
```

I'd like `.post` `div`s encapsulated two at a time with a `div` (say with the class `.page`) so the markup would look like:

```
<div class='book'>
    <div class='page'>
        <div class='post text'>one</div>
        <div class='post photo'>two</div>
    </div>
    <div class='page'>
        <div class='post quote'>three</div>
        <div class='post video'>four</div>  
    </div>
    <div class='page'>  
        <div class='post audio'>five</div>
        <div class='post link'>six</div>
    </div>
    <div class='page'>    
        <div class='post text'>seven</div>
        <div class='post video'>eight</div>
    </div>
    <div class='page'>    
        <div class='post quote'>nine</div>
        <div class='post link'>ten</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is for a tumblr layout. I want the layout to look like a book in which you can flip through posts like pages a la: http://jsfiddle.net/9fdk047t/.

I ran into some issues with `z-index` & `transition` while trying to do without a wrapper `div` for `.post`s.

I used ten just as an example. There could be 1-10 `.post`s on a page, so if there are odd number of `.post`s on a page the last encapsulating `div` should only host one `.post`.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jklm313/Upb3S/1/

Thank you for you help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Could be done using `.wrapAll()` method:

```
$('.post').each(function (i) {
    if (!(i % 2)) $(this).next('.post').addBack().wrapAll('<div class="page"/>');
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/TtSFL/1/)

Comment: Awesome! Let me just play around with the demo for a few minutes before I accept your answer! (I've already accepted it in my heart).

Comment: This is suitable, A. Wolff! Thanks a million! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var posts = $('.post');
for(var i=0; i < posts.size(); i+=2) {
    var group = $(posts.get(i)).add($(posts.get(i+1)));
    group.addClass('group');
    $('.group').wrapAll('<div class="page" />');
    group.removeClass('group');
}
```

Comment: A. Wolff's answer is more compact

Comment: Thank you, Samy, yours does work, but A. Wolff's answer seems to be the better solution. Cheers! :)

Answer (score 1):

Wolff's answer is definitely compact, i learned a lot from it
 Here is what i tried, the lengthy one.. :)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var book = $('.book');
    var postgroups = [];
    var postitems = [];
    var addItems = function () {
        var grpDiv = $('<div class ="page"/>');
        $(grpDiv).append(postitems);
        postitems = [];
        postgroups.push(grpDiv);
    }
    $('.post').each(function (index, item) {
        postitems.push(item);
        if ((index + 1) % 2 == 0) {
            addItems();
        }
    });
    if (postitems.length > 0) {
        addItems();
    }
    if (postgroups.length > 0) {
        $(book).empty();
        $(book).append(postgroups);
    }
});
```